# Why is Ubuntu 18.04 using Kernel 4.15

Tags: kernel, 18.04, lts

Why is Ubuntu 18.04 using Kernel 4.15 although that's not an LTS-Kernel? 
Since 18.04 is supported for at least 5 years that seems like a strange choice.